Walking all OIDs from base OID using walkCmd using pysnmp-lextudio
I'm new to pysnmp(-lextudio) and have zero experience with asyncio as well. I'm trying to walk all OIDs from a base OID (ciscoSmartLicMIB - .1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.831). Apparently the old way to do this was to use nextCmd with lexicographicMode=False, but that's been changed in pysnmp-lextudio, and the new method is to use walkCmd. I've been unable to get even the simple example in the docs to work, however.
I tried the example in the docs:
from pysnmp.hlapi.asyncio import *

g = await walkCmd(SnmpEngine(),
            CommunityData('public'),
            UdpTransportTarget(('demo.pysnmp.com', 161)),
            ContextData(),
            ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('SNMPv2-MIB', 'sysDescr')))

next(g)

but get:
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: 'await' outside function

Does anyone have a working example of walking all child OIDs of a top-level OID (and only child OIDs) using walkCmd?

https://docs.lextudio.com/pysnmp/examples/

@LexLi
So the best "example" is this one:
https://docs.lextudio.com/pysnmp/examples/hlapi/asyncio/manager/cmdgen/walking-operations
The problem is I have already tried it, and since it relies on bulkCmd instead of walkCmd or bulkWalkCmd, it continues fetching OIDs past the end of the parent tree.
Specifically isEndOfMib(varBinds) is never True.

I believe I've managed to refactor the example at Walking Operations based on Github issue etingof/pysnmp#233 to make it work:
import asyncio
from pysnmp.hlapi.asyncio import *


async def run(varBinds):
    snmpEngine = SnmpEngine()
    initialVarBinds = varBinds
    while True:
        errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBindTable = await bulkCmd(
            snmpEngine,
            UsmUserData("usr-none-none"),
            UdpTransportTarget(("demo.pysnmp.com", 161)),
            ContextData(),
            0,
            50,
            *varBinds,
        )

        if errorIndication:
            print(errorIndication)
            break
        elif errorStatus:
            print(
                f"{errorStatus.prettyPrint()} at {varBinds[int(errorIndex) - 1][0] if errorIndex else '?'}"
            )
        else:
            for varBindRow in varBindTable:
                for idx, varBind in enumerate(varBindRow):
                    if initialVarBinds[0][idx].isPrefixOf(varBind[0]):
                        print(" = ".join([x.prettyPrint() for x in varBind]))
                    else:
                        return

        varBinds = varBindTable[-1]
        if isEndOfMib(varBinds):
            break

        return


asyncio.run(
    run([ObjectType(ObjectIdentity("TCP-MIB")), ObjectType(ObjectIdentity("IP-MIB"))])
)


You can accept your own answer to close the discussion.

@LexLi I think you have some misunderstandings if you think that a Q/A set is a discussion that can be closed and another one if you think that accepting an answer is for closing.
